# How to preserve localStorage when redirecting to a new external url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, local-storage, redux-saga

I'm facing an issue where I can't save the localStorage across redirects.
Here is my code:

```
// Call newSitelogin(). Set response(credentials) to localStorage. Redirect to new url.
newSitelogin({ uuid, password })
  .then(() => {
    window.open(process.env.NEW_SITE_URL); // This line clears localStorage.
  })
  .catch(() => replaceRouteWith('/'));
```

Endpoint to call the api and set the response in localStorage

```
newSitelogin(payload) {
  return yield put.resolve({
      [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: `/auth/hubv3-login`,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        types: [
          ACTION.LOGIN_REQUEST_PERFORM,
          {
            type: ACTION.LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS,
            payload: (action, state, res) =>
              getJSON(res).then(json => localStorage.setItem('credentials', JSON.stringify(json))), // setting response to localStorage.
          },
          ACTION.LOGIN_REQUEST_FAILURE,
        ],
      },
  });
};
```

I can see that the credentials are rightly stored in the localStorage of my application:
[image]

But they are not preserved when i redirect to a new url using `window.open(process.env.NEW_SITE_URL)`.

[image]

How do i make sure that the `credentials` object is carried over when redirecting to a new url?
I cannot use sessions and cookies due to the logic written in the app that i'm redirecting to. It only looks for `credentials` in localStorage.

Comment: looks like the url is different. are you redirecting to an external link?

Comment: yes im redirecting to an external url

Comment: localstorage in only preserved within the same host

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue in the past. localStorage is only preserved per website. What i did was i attached the user credentials in cookies.